# Complete uninstall and re-install of PHP on Centos 7

Tags: php, mysql, installation, centos7, yum

I needed try PHP 5.6 and 5.5 on on Centos 7.  So, I installed them overtop of a perfect working installation of PHP 7.1. I followed the instructions here: https://www.mojowill.com/geek/howto-install-php-5-4-5-5-or-5-6-on-centos-6-and-centos-7/

Basically, I edited the remi repo config file to enable PHP 5.6 and 5.5 and installed PHP 5.6. I tested what I wanted to test and tried to switch back by disabling the repos and uninstall all php and then reinstall again. Now I have problems.

Here are the symptoms and what I've tried.

I get a message on a WordPress installation "`Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.`"

```
# php -v
PHP **7.2.14** (cli) (built: Jan  8 2019 14:05:15) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group

<? phpinfo() ?> works but says php version **7.1.24**
```

I tried to check if php-mysql is still installed:

```
# yum list installed | grep php
php.x86_64                              7.2.14-1.el7.remi              @remi-php72
php-cli.x86_64                          7.2.14-1.el7.remi              @remi-php72
php-common.x86_64                       7.2.14-1.el7.remi              @remi-php72
php-gd.x86_64                           7.2.14-1.el7.remi              @remi-php72
php-json.x86_64                         7.2.14-1.el7.remi              @remi-php72
php-mysqlnd.x86_64                      7.2.14-1.el7.remi              @remi-php72
php-pdo.x86_64                          7.2.14-1.el7.remi              @remi-php72
php-pecl-mcrypt.x86_64                  1.0.1-6.el7.remi.7.2           @remi-php72


# yum install php-mysql
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.layeronline.com
 * epel: mirror.uic.edu
 * extras: centos.mirror.globo.tech
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * remi: repo1.ash.innoscale.net
 * remi-php72: repo1.ash.innoscale.net
 * remi-safe: repo1.ash.innoscale.net
 * updates: centos.mirror.ca.planethoster.net
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Package php-mysql-5.4.45-16.el7.remi.x86_64 is obsoleted by php-mysqlnd-7.2.14-1.el7.remi.x86_64 which is already installed
```

Is there any easy resolution to this mess, or should I just fresh install the whole development machine.

Comment: Remi sez: "it's not my fault if my packages break your server, you shouldn't have used them." 1. Blow it all away and use docker if you need parallel installs on Centos. 2. Use the [IUS](https://ius.io/) repo instead. 3. Use a not-EOL version of PHP, which is 7.1-7.3 atm.

Comment: I'm going to look up docker and maybe take that advice.  Embarrassed to say that I have heard about, but not looked into it yet.  I'm noob trying to develop a web-stack for Centos 7.  I will just have to re-install this development machine that acts as a server-sandbox.

Comment: When you use remi installs, you can use the `remi-safe` repo instead. This allows you to use separate installation paths for the PHP installations, without affecting your core repo installation. Similar to the IUS or SCL repositories  To do a complete removal, use `yum history undo <id>` and rollback each history entry sequentially until you are back to your original configuration. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/64069 Keep in mind this will not undo any configuration file changes you made manually - such as with php.ini.

Comment: @fyrye Your solution worked perfectly.  I will mark as the correct answer if you submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 8):

First remove everything regarding old php version (will take some time...)

```
    sudo yum remove --setopt=clean_requirements_on_remove=1 php php-pear php-mysql php-cli php-common mod-php
```

then, install newer version (will take even more time)

```
    sudo yum install mod_php70u php70u-cli php70u-mysqlnd
```

dont forget to do restart and check
            sudo apachectl restart
            systemctl status httpd

If you're running fpm with NGinX then use following uninstall (this will keep the config's just o remove packages / dependencies)

```
    sudo yum remove --setopt=clean_requirements_on_remove=1 php-fpm php-cli php-common php7-fpm php7-cli php7-common
```

and install

```
    sudo yum install php7-fpm-nginx php7-cli php7-mysqlnd
```

(use [72] instead of [7] if you need to)

save, exit and restart

```
    sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
    sudo systemctl restart nginx #(or whatever you use)
```

please consider stepping down to version 7.1, as that might be a little less pain connecting modules than latest version, especially on always problematic centOS

(thanks @fyrye for options on remove)

Comment: I also recommend adding `--setopt=clean_requirements_on_remove=1` to your `yum remove`, to ensure associated dependencies that may conflict with the core packages are also removed. See the yum remove section of http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum.8.html for more information.